# HELP with wireframing 3d artwork

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I want to create this but im having trouble with creating it with extruding. Any recommendations? I want to fill the font and leave the bottom transparent exactly like this

[image: 3d wireframe text with filled font]

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator's classic 3D extrude effect can help you to make something resembling. An example:

[image]

I left out the background image, I have the default black wireframe and brown face fill color to make it visible on the white artboard. The colors could be adjusted easily as one likes.

I started by writing something. In the right it has got some envelope distortion just for fun. The text was outlined and the envelope distortion is expanded. Everything could be kept as well editable in images this simple. Illustrator can work to some degree without suffocating also if the effects are kept alive for future edits.

[image]

The distorted version got classic 3D effect Extrude & Bevel. At first the shading was "wireframe" and good watching direction + extrusion depth were adjusted. After it the shape was duplicated.

The 3D effect of the duplicate was opened in the appearance panel and the shading was changed to "no shading". The extrusion depth was changed to zero. The viewing angle was kept intact. Both versions are in the next screenshot:

[image]

The final version was got by aligning the versions. They snap easily if the 3D effects are fixed at first by applying Object > Expand Appearance.

The version with zero expansion depth is needed. The version which got only the envelope distortion wouldn't fit.